# Calibrating Probabilities worse than Original Model even though better performance on calibration curve? (in R / Caret)

Tags: r, classification, unbalanced-classes, caret, calibration

I'm currently working on the exercises of the book 'Applied Predictive Modeling' by Kuhn and Johnson (using R and caret) and am stuck at the issue of 'Calibrating Probabilities'.

Exercise 12.3 shows a problem linked to openly available data on churning:

```
library(C50)
data(churn)
table(churnTrain$Class
```

First of all I fit some linear classification models (the chapter is also about linear classification models so I did not go further than that for the exercises).

I found that LDA had the best fit with a sensitivity of 0.24 and specificity of 0.96. All of the five models had a very low sensitivity so this is actually the problem of this task I guess.

But then later I try calibration. By that I try to refit probabilities of Naive Bayes and of another model. When doing the calibration curve it looks like the Naive Bayes recalibration fits very well!

But then I try a confusion matrix between the estimated values through the Naive Bayes correction and the testing sample and see that it became worse: a sensitivity of 0.12.

And this is what I don't understand: it looks on the curve as if Naive Bayes fits very well to the line - but so why is the final prediction worse? Did I maybe do something completely wrong?

I am attaching here a reduced code of what I've done:
Thanks,
Nebi

```
library(C50)
library(caret)
data(churn)
str(churnTrain)
table(churnTrain$churn)

tr_y<-churnTrain$churn
te_y<-churnTest$churn

data_temp<- predict(dummyVars(~ ., data = churnTrain[,-length(churnTrain)]), newdata = churnTrain[,-length(churnTrain)])
test_temp<- predict(dummyVars(~ ., data = churnTest[,-length(churnTest)]), newdata = churnTest[,-length(churnTest)])



predictorInfo<-nearZeroVar(data_temp, saveMetrics = TRUE)
summary(predictorInfo)
vector<-!predictorInfo$nzv
data_temp<-data_temp[,vector]
test_temp<-test_temp[,vector]





correlations = cor(data_temp)
highCorrpp <- findCorrelation(correlations)

data_temp <- data_temp[, -highCorrpp]
test_temp <- test_temp[, -highCorrpp]



#no missing values
sum(!complete.cases(data_temp))



ctrl<- trainControl(method="cv",number=10,
                    summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                    classProbs=TRUE)

tr_x<-data_temp

te_x<-test_temp

#######I CUT OUT HERE THE OTHER MODELS

ldaMod<-train(x=tr_x,y=tr_y,
              method="lda",
              metric="ROC",
              preProcess=c("center","scale","BoxCox"),
              tuneLength = 15,
              trControl=ctrl)
ldaMod


ldaPred<-predict(ldaMod,te_x)
confusionMatrix(ldaPred,te_y)

ldaProb<-predict(ldaMod,te_x, type="prob")


glm.rocCurve = pROC::roc( response=te_y, predictor=ldaProb[,1] )
glm.rocCurve
plot(glm.rocCurve,legacy.axes=TRUE)

comb_te<-as.data.frame(te_x)
comb_te$y<-te_y#sic damit y bei beiden tr_y heisst

comb_te$ldaProb<-ldaProb[,1]
liftCurve<- lift(y~ldaProb,data=comb_te)
liftCurve

xyplot(liftCurve,
       auto.key=list(columns=2,
                     lines=TRUE,
                     points=FALSE))



calCurve <- calibration(y~ldaProb,data=comb_te)
calCurve
xyplot(calCurve,auto.key=list(columns=2))

comb_train<-as.data.frame(tr_x)
comb_train$y<-tr_y
sub_two<-predict(ldaMod,tr_x, type="prob")
comb_train$ldaProb<-sub_two[,1]



sigmoidalCal<-glm(relevel(y,ref="no")~ldaProb,
                  data=comb_train,
                  family=binomial)
coef(summary(sigmoidalCal))

sigmoidProbs<-predict(sigmoidalCal,newdata=comb_te[,"ldaProb",drop=FALSE],
                      type="response")


comb_te$LDAsigmoid<-sigmoidProbs

library(klaR)
BayesCal<-NaiveBayes(y~ldaProb,data=comb_train,usekernel=TRUE)
BayesProb<-predict(BayesCal,newdata=comb_te[,"ldaProb",drop=FALSE])
comb_te$LDABayes<-BayesProb$posterior[,"yes"]
head(comb_te)

#this is the curve that shows that NaiveBayes is performing well!
calCurve2<-calibration(y~ldaProb+LDAsigmoid+LDABayes, data=comb_te)
xyplot(calCurve2,auto.key=list(columns=3))

#and here is the confusion matrix showing that sensitivity is even lower!
confusionMatrix(BayesProb$class,comb_te$y)
```

Comment: I run your example code. Please note that all models have rather low Cohen's $k$ ($\leq 0.25$). While clearly no particular metric is a panacea, this suggests that none of them really does very good to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Sensitivity, specificity, and a confusion matrix are at odds with optimal prediction.  See [here](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/03/damage-caused-by-classification.html) for more information.  Calibration and predictive discrimination are all important.  Calibration should be assessed using a flexible continuous calibration curve, accounting for overfitting.  Predictive discrimination should be assessed using proper accuracy scoring rules combined with the semi-proper $c$-index (AUROC).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and insightful article. I understand that the AUROC is for optimal prediction overall more important than sensitivity and specificity. However, I am also in several aspects more confused now than before. I will try to find out more about these issues. For example in such an example, where 'yes' is so badly predicted, I thought that it would be worth to make a trade-off between ROC and sensitivity. Also the differentiation that you mention between the calibration on the one hand and the predictive discrimination makes me think...

Comment: That is exactly not the way to think about it in my humble opinion.  Please read the article carefully at the link above and read also [this](http://www.fharrell.com/2017/01/classification-vs-prediction.html).